# HTML Search Function Using JScript (JQuery) and JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a HTML file that uses some JScript that I found online and would like it to incorporate it into a simple page for internal use that can be used to quickly look up information.

The page would present the data from a JSON file that is stored on the server.

I can add the JSON data directly to the HTML file, but would like a file that we can export  from time to time in-place with the new data and now have to manually edit the HTML files directly.

So far I have this HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
var a = ['https://url.com/data.json'];

jQuery('#search-json-submit').click(function() {
    jQuery('#search-output').html('');
    var search_query = jQuery('#search-json-input').val();
    var search_query_regex = new RegExp(".*"+search_query+".*", "g");
    jQuery.each(a, function(k, v) {
        if(v['name'].match(search_query_regex) ||
           v['id'].match(search_query_regex) ||
           v['location'].match(search_query_regex)) {
               jQuery('#search-output').append('<li>Search results found in: '+'{ name: "'+v['name']+'", id: "'+v['id']+'", location: "'+v['location']+'" } </li>');
        }
    });
});

});//]]> 

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="search-json-input" />
<input type="button" id="search-json-submit" value="search" />
<h4>Search Results</h4>
<ol id="search-output">

</ol>

</body>
</html>
```

My JSON file is the following text:

```
{"name":"mynewname", "id" : "t2", "location" : "India"},
{"name":"mynewname1", "id" : "t21", "location" : "China"},
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong to link the variable `a` to the JSON file URL to search.

I had a look at another page and it linked the JSON file using

```
$.getJSON('https://url.com/data.json')
```

but I can't get that to work either.

The original `a` variable for this example is:

```
var a  =[
    {"name":"mynewname", "id" : "t2", "location" : "India"},
    {"name":"mynewname1", "id" : "t21", "location" : "China"},    
];
```

Once I get the search function to work, I can then format it properly and find a more suitable solution in the long term. For now I would like to just kick start this and get it up and running.

Comment: what error are you getting with $.getJSON('https://url.com/data.json'). Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ You need to consider issues like async and cross-domain request (if applicable)

Comment: I don't get any response when I use the `$.getJSON('url.com/data.json')` in the code. The page just sits there.

Comment: json is missing outer `[]`

Comment: @charlietfl do you mean $.getJSON[('https://url.com/data.json')]

Comment: no I mean in the data shown. should have same structure as `var a` but without the variable assignment

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function () {
    jQuery.getJSON("data.json", function (a) {
        jQuery('#search-json-submit').click(function () {
            jQuery('#search-output').html('');
            var search_query = jQuery('#search-json-input').val();
            var search_query_regex = new RegExp(".*" + search_query + ".*", "g");
            jQuery.each(a, function (k, v) {
                if (v['name'].match(search_query_regex) || v['id'].match(search_query_regex) || v['location'].match(search_query_regex)) {
                    jQuery('#search-output').append('<li>Search results found in: ' + '{ name: "' + v['name'] + '", id: "' + v['id'] + '", location: "' + v['location'] + '" } </li>');
                }
            });
        })
    });
});
```

Make sure that data.json is located on same server(domain) as your js/html(cross origin policy).

Update: http://jsfiddle.net/m7jocxwh/1/

Comment: If you are calling the `data.json` file directly, why do you run the function with the `a` variable in it? Do I need to declare that separately in a different function? Here: `jQuery.getJson("data.json", function (a) {` There also looks to be a missing close bracket on that line for the `("data.json",` component.

Comment: I don't think there is any problem in ```{``` check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m7jocxwh/1/ I have tested it with some dummy data. You need ```a``` in function because the API is designed that way & it doesn't directly returns the data but asynchronously passes it to the callback function.